# PHP return value mystique

Tags: php

I'm not a PHP developer, so the following question may have a simple answer which I miss.

I have a function (like the following one here) inside a class, and I can't figure out what is it good for if the returned value of the of check_min function is not assigned anywhere (and does not re-return)...

```
function a() 
{
 ...

  $this->check_min(); //check_min function returns a boolean

 ...
 }
```

Comment: Well, does `check_min` do anything else besides returning a boolean at the end? If not, calling it indeed seems nonsensical

Comment: Does `check_min()` do any other work besides returning a value? If not, then it isn't of much use. Keep in mind that _other work_ could include database triggers that are not apparent, or other observer methods.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to call it there if one of the following is true:

- Could it throw exceptions in case of an error or an invalid variable in the class?
- Does it change any class or object properties?
- Does it call other methods or functions?
- Does it generally do anything other than checking something and returning true/false based on that?

It could be that the true/false return is only to indicate that the function was executed successfully, rather than the check was completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It's no good unless check_min() does something that has side effects.  Or possible throws and exception or error if some object variable is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If check_min would modify any value of the class, it would make sense to call it. The boolean could be an indicator whether its' execution was sccessfull.

By reading the name of the function I would say that for example, it could determine which of its' values is the smallest and put a flag on it or something. If there was no smallest value, it could return false.

But it would be rather strange/misleading to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `check_min()` method must have some [side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29), i.e., any state modifications etc. performed within the `check_min()` method are carried out. In this particular case nobody cares about the return value, though.